# C++ error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions struct

Tags: c++

I get the error message :
error: a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions struct
in my header file..

```
/*
 * stud.h
 *
 *  Created on: 12.11.2013
 *      Author: 
 */

//stud.h: Definition der Datenstruktur Stud
#ifndef _STUD_H
#define _STUD_H


struct Stud{
        long matrnr;
        char vorname[30];
        char name[30];
        char datum[30];
        float note;
    };

extern Stud mystud[];

int einlesen (struct Stud[]);
void bubbleSort(struct Stud[] , int );
void ausgeben(struct Stud[], int);

#endif
```

where is the problem?

Comment: when I remove the extern, Eclipse complains about multiple definition of several classes........ first defined here....

Comment: Remove `extern Stud mystud[]`.  Redesign your code to use no global variables.

Comment: Is this being compiled as C or C++?  It looks like C.

Comment: I get no errors compiling this as C++. If it's actually C (in which case please update the tags), then you'll need `struct Stud` not just `Stud` as the type of `mystud`. In either case, you shouldn't use reserved names like `_STUD_H` for the include guard.

Comment: I removed extern Stud mystud[] but now it complains about "multiple definition of the classes... einlesen() bubbleSort() ausgebe()..."

Comment: the thing is , I used Eclipse CDT to compile this, however, when I compile it in the cmd shell in windows with gcc -o prog CSVEinlesenMain.cpp  , it compiles without problems lol

Comment: is there any way maybe to include an extern makefile to get this to run or to create a makefile for my project in Eclipse CDT? how can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I would say that your problem is with the

```
extern Stud mystud[];
```

It probably should change to something more like

```
extern struct Stud* mystud;
```

and then in the implementation file for this header:

```
struct Stud stud_storage[SIZE];
struct Stud* mystud = stud_storage;
```

I think you could possibly get away with the `extern struct Stud mystud[];` declaration with some compilers that will always convert that internally the corresponding pointer type, but not with all compilers (Need to double check my ANSI standard (C89) to be sure, but the conversion is only allowed by the standard in function declarations and definitions not in variable declarations.)